# Selecting specific rows of a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a 6639x5 matrix in Matlab and I would like to select certain specific rows in a particular order( say 1st,11th,21st,31st rows... and subsequent additions of 10 until end) to form a new matrix.Any ideas?
Thank you,
Oti.

Answer (score 8):

```
subset = a(1:10:end, :);
```

Selects every 10th row until the end, and all columns.

Example:

```
>> a = magic(5)

a =

    17    24     1     8    15
    23     5     7    14    16
     4     6    13    20    22
    10    12    19    21     3
    11    18    25     2     9

>> a(1:2:end, :)

ans =

    17    24     1     8    15
     4     6    13    20    22
    11    18    25     2     9
```

Comment: The first row is not in every 10th row:)

Comment: Thank you very much @Andrew Mao for the help.